# code: "auth/argument-error", message: "reCAPTCHA container is either not found or already contains inner elements!", a: null Angular

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am trying to do sms/phone validation of my angular website through fire base until now i have tried the code below

```
firebase.auth().settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting = true;

var phoneNumber = "+16505554567";
var testVerificationCode = "123456";

// This will render a fake reCAPTCHA as appVerificationDisabledForTesting is true.
// This will resolve after rendering without app verification.
var appVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');
// signInWithPhoneNumber will call appVerifier.verify() which will resolve with a fake
// reCAPTCHA response.
firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
    .then(function (confirmationResult) {
      // confirmationResult can resolve with the fictional testVerificationCode above.
      return confirmationResult.confirm(testVerificationCode)
    }).catch(func`enter code here`tion (error) {
      // Error; SMS not sent
      // ...
    });
```

The above code is mentioned in firebase documentation
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#integration-testing
I have setup the config file for firebase and initialized firebase app and my code in template file is

```
<div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
```

i want to test my sms service
My firebase version is "firebase": "^8.8.1",
when i run the code above i get this error

> t {code: "auth/argument-error", message: "reCAPTCHA container is
> either not found or already contains inner elements!", a: null}

I want to test my verification without CAPTCHA
All help is appreciated